Circuit lights dimming ~5% suddenly and repeatedly
I have been doing some electrical work but the kitchen/dining room lights are one of many circuits have not touched at all except for putting a few Lutron smart dimmers in the place of knob dimmers.
I recently noticed a floor lamp with a built-in LED dim about 5% repeatedly for a random amount of time before stopping. Then I noticed the kitchen lights on the same circuit as the floor lamp outlet (only the outlet that has a light switch is on the light circuit) dim in the same way, but hard to tell if they’re synced. I put my saw/corded power tools and basement heater outlets (1 gfci and 1 duplex in a large new work box with 1/2” mud ring) on their own dedicated 20 amp breaker (ran a 20 ft 10/2 for it) just to prevent the massive voltage drop (heater caused a 20V drop) and inrush current (dewalt mitre saw turned out all lights on the circuit) they caused. This dimming was noticed after that, so I’m naturally getting nervous it’s not a coincidence even though I never touched this circuit and it’s been over a month since installing the dimmers. I just installed LED bulbs that Lutron recommend thinking the incandescent 390 W load in the kitchen was overloading the Lutron dimmer when ganged with a companion but it happened again. I found if I toggle the breaker it stops this behavior for a while, so I just replaced the breaker. We just got this house this year, so most of the lights were here already. I’ve read a loose neutral could cause this, but it only seems to happen to lights on this specific circuit and I torque everything that has a spec when I install something.
I will check the connections if changing the breaker doesn’t fix it, but the wiring in this house was done in the 60s and the paths they took often don’t make sense to me. I have also seen wire nuts just fall off upon opening, so maybe I shook one loose. Any ideas what it could be if the breaker isn’t the problem and if I don’t end up finding a loose neutral? Thanks!

Do you know the size of your panel/service in amps?  The 60s were not known for large panels/service sizes.  Might be loose connections or close to the max your panel can delivered.

I believe it’s a 150 A service panel. I have turned off everything that draws a large load and tested this and it doesn’t seem to be related to load. The new CH breakers don’t grab onto the panel bars as well as the old ones that had metal claws or whatever on the back. But that breaker was an old one. The new breaker does move around a bit if messed with since it is the top breaker under the main shutoff separation, which I don’t love. But with that panel cover on it is fixed in place well. I tugged on the neutrals and they all seem fine. I am running out of neutrals though. It’s pretty full.

What is the make of the box with the breakers in, and what is the make of the new breaker?

Get a baseline voltage reading of hot 1-hot 2, hot 1-neutral, hot 2-neutral when things are normal. Easiest is clothes dryer receptacle if you have a 240V/120V typical clothes dryer. Then see if you can get readings at the same location then the lights are dimming. That will provide some clues - e.g., 240V/120V/120V unchanged means specific to the problem circuits; 240V/110V/130V (or other variance between the hot/neutral readings) may mean a lost (or marginal) neutral, either in the main panel or at the meter), 230V/115V/115V may mean an overall house overload causing a drop, etc.

It’s a cutler hammer load center and the new breakers are the Eaton CH breakers. They look identical except the new ones have a plastic hook on the back while the old ones have metal. The hooks are the same but the metal ones appear to trip when pulled which is why they feel more secure. I’m assuming it’s a cost saving thing over time… like everything.
As for the voltage: the dimming is transient, so I can try to measure a drop. The 240 outlet is a bit unbalanced by a volt or so last time I measured. It was around 123/122 without turning everything off in the house.

I also rented a thermal camera to check for air leaks, so I’m going to inspect outlets, switches, and the panel for hot spots.

"I have also seen wire nuts just fall off upon opening" is a pretty good sign that somone not very good at wiring has been at yours, or there's something else going on like "some of the wiring is aluminum, some is copper" that we can't see. It strongly suggests literally checking every junction box and every wire nut. While doing that, keep an eye out for backstabbed (spring held, not the ones where the screw clamps the back entry wire) connections, which are a very common cause of intermittent power faults. Might as well bring a torque driver and check the screws, too.

The voltage dips from 122-123 to 116 on my gfci checker (which is slow, so it could go lower. I need to get my dvm). It only appears on this circuit and within minutes it has stopped. It is about a 1 second or less transient spaced by a few seconds at irregular intervals. If it were at regular intervals I’d guess it is some kind of parasitic load from a compressor or something but the furnace is on its own circuit, the ac is off, and the fridge has its own circuit. The breaker change didn’t work, so I guess I’m going to get searching.
